# Connecting a meteor app to Steam

Tags: web-applications, meteor, authentication, steam

I'm trying to authenticate users using steam in my meteor app. I don't know if it's super simple, or just not really done because I can't find too much about it after some googling. The idea is to have a log in via steam button, similar to the popular log in via facebook or G+.

Comment: any luck with this? im currently looking around for the same kind of thing.